# `Please try installing a newer version of bash under /usr/local/bin/bash` message on mac

Tags: linux, bash, shell, homebrew

I am getting this error message, even though I have the updated bash running:

```
You are running on a Mac and your bash version is too old (< 4).
Please try installing a newer version of bash under /usr/local/bin/bash.
```

When I run `bash version`, I get this:

`GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin21.1.0)`

*which bash* returns `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`

But when I run `echo $BASH_VERSION`, I get an empty string. Any idea why this is happening?

I am running macOS Monterey - M1

Comment: What kind of output do you expect with `echo ${bash}`?

Comment: I think you want `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: The error message says it's using `/usr/local/bin/bash`, not `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`. Add a symlink in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: When you run `bash version`, your current shell (which may be an old bash, a new bash, or maybe zsh, or even something else) starts a new instance of the first `bash` on your PATH and it will tell you its version. That will tell you nothing at all about the shell you are currently in.

Comment: @Barmar echo ```$BASH_VERSION``` returns an empty string too. Let me add the symlink as suggested.

Comment: Note that the default shell in Terminal windows is `zsh`, not `bash`.

Comment: Run `echo $ZSH_VERSION`

Comment: *What* produces that error? Sounds like a script that is trying to use `/bin/bash` specifically, not whatever `bash` is specified by your `PATH`.

Comment: run `declare -p | grep VERSION` and check what's there